# How to hide TreeView root?

Tags: wpf, treeview

I am working on WPF `TreeView`, and I want to hide the parent of the tree. For this case the parent is:

```
var parent = new TreeViewModel() { Value = "Main Root" };
```

I populated my tree structure using this method:

```
public ObservableCollection<MessageElementViewModel> GetAllTreeNodes()
{
    List<TreeViewModel> reqNodes = GetRequestTreeNodesFromModel();  // req
    //List<TreeViewModel> respNodes = GetRequestTreeNodesFromModel();  // res

    var request = new TreeViewModel();
    var response = new TreeViewModel();
    var parent = new TreeViewModel() { Value = "Main Root" };

    for (int i = 0; i < wsMethodNameList.Count; i++)
    {
        var child = new TreeViewModel { Value = wsMethodNameList[i] };
        parent.Children.Add(child);
        var requestChild = new TreeViewModel { Value = requestXmlList[i] };

        requestChild.Children = reqNodes;
        child.Children.Add(requestChild);

        var responseChild = new TreeViewModel { Value = responseXmlList[i] };
        responseChild.Children = reqNodes; // change to response nodes
        child.Children.Add(responseChild);
    }
    return new ObservableCollection<TreeViewModel> { parent};
```

xaml

```
<TreeView Margin="644,137,6,6" Grid.RowSpan="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MessageElements,  Mode=TwoWay}">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MessageElementViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path= Children }">
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Name}" Content="{Binding Name}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

ViewModel

```
public ObservableCollection<MessageElementViewModel> MessageElements
{
    get { return messageElement; }
    set
    {
        if (messageElement == value)
            return;
        messageElement = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("MessageElements");
    }
}
```

Loading data

```
public void LoadData()
{
    this.MessageElements = treeVModel.GetAllTreeNodes();
}
```

On my xaml  I want to hide `parent = new TreeViewModel() { Value = "Main Root" };`.

How can I achieve that? I tried to give it an empty string but it still shows the expand icon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply don't bind to the root itself but its children.

Comment: `ItemsSource="{Binding MessageElements[0].Children}"`

Comment: @AydaSayed: `1`? If your tree has one root then `1` is out of range.

Comment: my tree has one root(parent) and another two sub-roots(request and response)